# Which CMS will be better to load different templates in different pages in CI?

Tags: codeigniter, templates, pyrocms

I am trying to look forward for the CMS in which the designer can easily implement the different templates for different pages so that the site can be completed in short time even without the web developer. Can you suggest the appropriate CMS for that except JOOMLA? Currently I am thinking of using pyrocms. Will pyrocms support the feature?

Comment: yes, pyrocms will do.

Comment: Would you please add some logic regarding how can it be implemented?

Comment: Implementation details are an entirely different question than whether a feature is supported; you will probably not get any explanations here - at least without starting a new question that specifically asks about implementation, and even then you may just be told to `ask Google` until you demonstrate you have already tried something on your own. You could start by reading existing [SO questions tagged `pyromcs`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyrocms).

Comment: I am sure you haven's seen this one. [Halogy](http://www.halogy.com/) made on Codeigniter.

Answer (score 4):

I got the answer to the question. Drupal would be the best CMS for this case. In Drupal you can add easily maintain the whole site from the backend even without coding single line. The views can be maintained easily in drupal from the backend so that even the designer can easily create the site. Even Multisite can be maintained in Drupal in which different sites can be accessed by single login.
The only disadvantage using Drupal is that the database size will be very heavy.

Answer (score 1):

I think drupal is very suitable as it has huge community support and hundreds of community supported themes and modules. However it all depends on your requirements and skill set. Following comparison might help you to decide between Drupal and pyrocms. http://vschart.com/compare/pyrocms/vs/drupal

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra CSS to a page in PyroCMS under Content > Pages > Edit Page > Design. You can also change the page layout on this page, which are created at Content > Pages > Layouts. This can be all done through the CMS, but will need some HTML or CSS knowledge.

You could ask someone to create some templates before-hand and you choose from them for each page, or you could tweak them yourself.

In my experience PyroCMS is much easier to use than Drupal and Joomla.